# php numbers formatting

Tags: php, rounding, number-formatting

I have this variable `$mynumber` that echos a number between 1 and 100, on the output, I need this number to be divided by 2, round it, and place a dot between the digits, like this:

```
<?php echo $mynumber ?>

//output e.g. 55
```

I need to output 2.7 instead ( 55/2 -> 27.5 -> 27 -> 2.7 )

I'm having troubles formatting it the right way, can you help me out?
Thanks

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: number_format($your_final_number, 1);

Comment: What if the number is 1 or 100?

Comment: Look into printf / sprintf. They may look confusing, but you should be able to find examples of what you're after.

Comment: 100 would become 5.0 but what about 1000?

Comment: Can you confirm that you want to round the number down in every case?

Comment: `printf("%.1f", (float)$mynumber/20);`

Comment: I think this is some basic non-applicable question, so I flagged it as "too localized". I mean just divide a number, search for a function that does the rounding or floor or whatever and then divide by 10 with some formatting (facepalm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$mynumber = 55;
echo (intval($mynumber/2))/10 . "\n";
?>
```

I assume you don't really want rounding but truncating since you wrote that 27.5 becomes 27, not 28.

Comment: Yes truncate the third digit if present, sorry. I'm doing some tests but your solution seem to be working. Thanks everyone

Comment: if you have negative numbers you have to decide if you want the behaviour of intval() or floor().

Answer (score 3):

if `$mynumber` is between 1-100 this should work:

```
<?php echo floor($mynumber/2)/10; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for?
This will round all values down.

`$mynumber = (floor($mynumber/2) /10);`

If you want to round values up or down dependant on the value itself, use the following:

`$mynumber = (round($mynumber/2) /10);`

Comment: this would output 2.8 for 55

Comment: Use `floor()` instead of `round()`

Comment: I read his question as he wanted to round it, not round it down but I see in his example, he wanted to go down on a .5!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $number = 55;

    $mynumber = floor($number/2);
    $chars = strlen($mynumber);
    $pos = substr($mynumber, $chars-1);
    $pos2 = substr($mynumber, $pos)+1;  
    $newNumber = (float)(str_replace($pos, '.', $mynumber).substr($mynumber, $pos2));
    echo $newNumber;
?>
```